# All registered domain names in the world

Tags: dns, domain-name

Is it possible to get a full list of all registered domain names in the world?

I have tried to look it up, but can not find any valid source.

Its okay if its a paid service.

Comment: It will be very helpful - http://jordan-wright.com/blog/2015/09/30/how-to-download-a-list-of-all-registered-domain-names/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not programming related

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not. That would require getting up-to-date and complete information from the registries for all the 1000+ top-level domains, and even if you were to go and ask all of them for it, some of them plain don't want you to know (like, for example, I'm guessing, `.MIL`).